# Who calls autorelease pool

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

Who calls autorelease pool or who manages it. I call autorelease on my variable which is inside a function, but who manages this autorelease call, the calling function, or the caller function or who does?

Comment: I'm not very well sure why the downvotes. This is a legitimate question involving correct use of autorelease and the operation of such. (Although it *is* covered in documentation..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are saying `autorelease`, don't. Stop using manual memory management and use ARC. It knows more than you do.

Okay, so let's say you *do* say `autorelease`. Then it is placed in the autorelease pool and its retain count remains incremented. Its retain count will be decremented again when the autorelease pool is drained. When *that* happens depends on what autorelease pool you're talking about.

- If you actually made this autorelease pool, then it drains when you tell it to `drain`. Under ARC, that happens when we come to the end of the `@autoreleasepool{}` directive block.
- If it's the default autorelease pool, the runtime takes care of it and you have no knowledge or control over the matter. You can be pretty sure there will be a drain call after all you code finishes and the app is idle, but there's nothing guaranteed about it.

Comment: My book will help you understand the autorelease mechanism: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_autorelease

Comment: Thanks Matt, i am using ARC, but was digging deep into autorelease...So the question...

Comment: "Then the retain count on this object is incremented and it is placed in the autorelease pool." Technically, calling `autorelease` on an object does not have any immediate effect on its retain count. Though I guess conceptually you could think of it as the calling scope "releasing" it combined with the autorelease pool "retaining" it, which cancel out.